# Using System.IO in UWP apps?

Tags: c#, reference, uwp, system

is it possible/allowed to use `System.IO` in UWP apps? I thought to know that I'm not supposed to use it since in UWP, files are stored as `StorageFile`.

Now I want to provide methods to zip files in UWP. I've tried solving it following [this thread.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/93836630-a47a-40d2-aaae-e70eb0e65bf4/uwpwrite-folder-to-zip-file?forum=wpdevelop) To use this solution, I would need to use `System.IO`. I didn't even test if this solution works because I am confused right now. I've been working on an UWP app for a bit longer than a month now and I'm pretty sure that I'm not supposed to use `System.IO` in UWP apps.

Am I missing a point here? Can we use `System.IO` in UWP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an entire MSDN page dedicated to this subject: [System.IO namespaces for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185496.aspx).

The [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive
class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx) which this question appears to be about is supported for UWP since Windows 8.